# Unaccounted trophy, not appearing in ID

Tags: achievements, ps3, psn, assassins-creed-3

I earned some trophies in AC3.
Unfortunately, my internet was *down* at the time, and I did not log in.
Therefore, the trophies are displayed as earned, but no time is displayed as for when they were achieved.

I think it not to be a co-incidence that these trophies are *not appearing* in my PSN ID even though I *synced* my profile with my save file.

**What do I do to display my rightly earned trophies?**

Comment: This is very strange, I've earned trophies while offline several times and never had problems syncing them. Could you please explain where do you see your trophies as earned without time displayed? When you check your "offline" trophies? What happens if you sync your trophies manually? (Under the XMB: PlayStation Network -> highlight Trophies and press triangle -> Sync Trophies)

Comment: Do the trophies show in your Offline trophies properly?

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes. They even display properly when I switch my Playstation Network>Trophy to **Online Mode**!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It's not showing up on my PSN ID (No trophy update on the 'recent trophies' and no increase in percentage of the level.)!

Comment: Please help, I have several **silvers** unaccounted for!

Comment: Try Syncing your profile as well. Can you see these trophies on your public trophy profile?

Comment: Use this link, change the username in the address bar to your PSN ID http://us.playstation.com/publictrophy/index.htm?onlinename=JohnoBoy

Comment: @JohnoBoy Yes I can see it on my Public Profile. That is weird.
I clearly remember my level % was 25% before syncing, and it remained the same after syncing.
NOTE: I am **level 8** so it is not possible that multiple silvers won't change my %. 
(Now, of course it's more cause I earned other trophies)

Comment: You can calculate your current level and percentage by giving values to each type of trophy earned. I'd check with [this guide](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/games/18347-trophy-points-guide.html) - compare it with your trophy numbers and see if they calculate correctly.

Comment: Here's a link to an online calculator http://ps3trophies.comyr.com/

Comment: @Siddhartha might as well delete this, or answer it yourself, so that it doesn't remain Unanswered.

Comment: I dunno. It's not inconceivable that someone else'll run afoul of a similar issue. I'm voting to leave this open for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was just a misunderstanding and though it didn't sync at first,
**eventually** it showed up in the PSN profile/ID.

Comment: This also happens, when you unlock steam achievements at the time when you have no connection to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try syncing the trophies, by pushing the Triangle button on the trophy list?

Source:

http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/general-ps3-discussion/180754-trophies-online-offline-mode.html

Comment: Already done that. Didn't work.